# migrate user from adfs to office 365

Tags: office-365

I am new to Office 365 and I want to know if it is possible to migrate user from ADFS to Office 365. Will that require a physical server?

Is that including with the non-premium version of Active Directory?

What part of self-service password resets is the premium version?